# Uploading files with nginx, node and express under pm2 getting Error: EACCES: permission denied mkdir '/var/virtual/upload/38'

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, permissions, upload

On my dev machine (Windows 10) this works just fine running the server with nodemon.  On the production machine, Ubuntu 18, using pm2 to fork the process under my user account "greg" I get:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/virtual/upload/38'
```

The folder permissions were all set to me and 766 folder permissions.

```
greg@node:/var/virtual$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 Jul 15 07:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4096 May  4 11:21 ../
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 13 13:24 portal/
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg     greg     4096 Jul 15 07:46 uploads/

greg@node:/var/virtual$ pm2 list
┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │      │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ server    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 21125    │ 38m    │ 0    │ online    │ 0.4%     │ 63.6mb   │ greg     │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

But any attempt to upload fails.  Is there some other user process that this needs to run under?  Is it node or nginx that is actually saving the file??

Comment: it's `/var/virtual/upload/`, not `/var/virtual/uploads/`.

Comment: of the six people that looked at that, you were the magic 7th that noticed.  not even the damn server team saw it.

Comment: does it work though? `mkdir -p` and `chown` should suffice.